# I want to (Lag or shift) a time series by a (day, week, month or year) without loops

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, lag, shift

I am basically trying to make new columns of my Time Serie and I want te lag of some days, weeks, months or years as wanted.
I have made a function that solves this problem but is highly ineficien.

```
def lag_N_period ( df, y , days_ago=0 , weeks_ago=0 , months_ago=0 , years_ago=0 ):
   


    skip = days_ago + weeks_ago*7 + months_ago*31 + years_ago*366 


    
    ## FEATURE NAME ## 
    feature_name = '' 
    
    if days_ago > 0  :
        feature_name = feature_name + str(days_ago) + 'days_' 
    if weeks_ago > 0  :
        feature_name = feature_name + str(weeks_ago) + 'weeks_'
    if months_ago > 0  :
        feature_name = feature_name + str(months_ago) + 'months_'        
    if years_ago > 0  :
        feature_name = feature_name + str(years_ago) + 'years_'        
        
    feature_name = feature_name + 'ago'



    
    df[feature_name] = [np.nan for i in range(len(df[objetivo])) ] #Creates NaN column named 'feature_name'

    
    for i in df.index[skip:]:

        j = i - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=days_ago , weeks=weeks_ago , months=months_ago , years=years_ago) 
        df[feature_name][i] = df[y][j]

    return df
```

The skip is just a int because if in the loop you call for a index in the dataframe and it doesn´t exist, you get an error, but anything else.

df is my dataframe with dates as index and 'y', the objective variable

```
            objective
date    
2018-01-01  3420
2018-01-02  100580
2018-01-03  78500
2018-01-04  72640
2018-01-05  64980
... ...
2021-01-27  76820
2021-01-28  90520
2021-01-29  81920
2021-01-30  20080
2021-01-31  0
```

I have try the .shift() function as .shift(1, period='M') but it's not the output y want.
The only case it works is when i just want the lag of 5 or some days ago llike, .shift(5)

Comment: "*I have try the .shift() function as .shift(1, period='M') but it's not the output y want.*" maybe you should provide a minimal example (with data) to illustrate what exactly you tried, how this is not what you want, and what you exactly want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dataframe with a `DatetimeIndex` which doesn't have any missing days like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": range(500)}, index=pd.date_range("2022-03-01", periods=500, freq="1D")
)

              A
2022-03-01    0
2022-03-02    1
...         ...
2023-07-12  498
2023-07-13  499
```

you could do the following

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

delta = relativedelta(months=1)
df["B"] = None  # None instead of other NaNs - can be changed
idx = df.loc[df.index[0] + delta:].index
df.loc[idx, "B"] = df.loc[[day - delta for day in idx], "A"].values
```

and get

```
              A     B
2022-03-01    0  None
2022-03-02    1  None
...         ...   ...
2023-07-12  498   468
2023-07-13  499   469
```

The `idx` is there to make sure that the actual shifting doesn't fail. It's the part you're trying to address by `skip`. (Your `skip` is actually a bit imprecise because you're using 31/366 days for month/year lengths universally.)

But be prepared to run into strange phenomena when you're using months and/or years. For example

```
from datetime import date

delta = relativedelta(months=1)
date(2022, 3, 30) + delta == date(2022, 3, 31) + delta
```

is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html), [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd

# Sample dataframe
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([('2021-01-01'), ('2021-01-02'), ('2022-01-01')], columns=['Date'])

# Contents of a
>>> a
         Date
0  2021-01-01
1  2021-01-02
2  2022-01-01

# Ensuring Date is a datetime column
>>> a['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['Date'])

# Adding a month to all of the dates
>>> a.Date.apply(lambda x: x + relativedelta(months=1))
0   2021-02-01
1   2021-02-02
2   2022-02-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: is now a way to join those dates objectives with the original dataframe ?

Comment: You can just apply these functions to the original dataframe rather than creating an entirely new dataframe. I simply created one as an example.